# What happens when Ramda function is given empty parameter?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

I just observed this behavior with Ramda function, and couldn't quite understand it. For the following binary function

```
const t1 = (a) => R.cond([ [R.T, R.identity] ] );
```

When both parameters are given, e.g.,

```
t1(1)({})
```

it returns `{}` as expected.

However, if called this way

```
t1(1)()
```

it returns a `[Function: f1]`.

What is actually going one here? Is the second parameter being defaulted to something, or treated as if it were never supplied?

Is there a way in Ramda to explicitly set a default value for the second parameter (e.g. to `{}`)?

Comment: @cubrr Thanks, Just fixed the typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first of all, I don't understand your function.  `R.cond([ [R.T, R.identity] ] )` is a slightly bizarre way to write what is essentially the identity function.  `cond` usually takes multiple predicate-action pairs, usually using the predicate `R.T` for the last one as a default (analogous to the `default` case of a `switch` statement.)

Wrapping this up in `(a) => R.cond([ [R.T, R.identity] ] )` simply gives you a function to which you pass any argument(s) you like, which are promptly ignored, giving back that odd identity function.

Like many functions created by Ramda, the output of `cond` is a *curried* function, using Ramda's expanded notion of currying, in which you can call the functions in various ways.  For example, if `g = curry(function f(a, b, c) {/* ... */})`, then all of these are equivalent to `f(a, b, c)`:

```
g(a, b, c)
g(a, b)(c)
g(a)(b, c)
g(a)(b)(c)
```

And if you call with fewer than the full complement of parameters, you get back another function:

```
g(a); //~> curry((b, c) => f(a, b, c))
g(a, b); //~> curry((c) => f(a, b, c))
```

This extends even to supplying no parameters at all:

```
g(); //~> curry((a, b, c) => f(a, b, c)),
```

This last is what you're noticing.  `t1(1)` returns that odd identity, `R.cond([ [R.T, R.identity] ] )`.  Because this function is curried, if you call it with no parameters, you get back something equivalent to that same identity function.

That should explain why the function behaves as it does.  I can't tell what fundamental problem you're trying to solve, so I don't know how to help...

Except that you mention defaulting, and it's possible that Ramda's [`defaultTo`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#defaultTo) might be of help.